# How do I update Big Query partition expiration using Python BigQuery Client?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

We are currently looking to clean up old Big Query data. While creating the dataset, tables and partitions, we did not update the expiration time until recently. So the old partitions do not have expiration time set. Only the newly created tables and partitions have expiration.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-partitioned-tables#bq

According to the above doc, it says to update partition expiry using SQL or bq commands or API. I want to be able to automate the whole process without manually running the commands for each of the dataset and I'll be able to run the script only from the server since our access is restricted.

Is there a way to automate the process using python script and Python BQ client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a example of update a table partition expiration using [google-cloud-bigquery](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-bigquery/):

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery

table_id = 'project_id.dataset_id.table_name'
partition_expiration_ms = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 # 30 days in milliseconds

client = bigquery.Client()

table_ref = client.get_table(table_id)  
table_ref.time_partitioning.expiration_ms = partition_expiration_ms 

client.update_table(table_ref, ["time_partitioning"])
```